# How to implement Gaussian Blur with cv2 correctly?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am getting the following error

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2d3a348b0b9b> in <module>()
     25 
     26 #gaussian blur (sigma = 1)
---> 27 gaus_blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(0,0), 1, 1)
     28 cv2_imshow(gaus_blur1[2000])
     29 

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:757: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'
```

When I am trying to do

```
for k in range (7165):
  img[k] = cv2.imread('/content/FIGURE/figure' + str(k) +'.png', 1) 
                                    #storing images into array of integers

img_neg = 255 - img    #taking the negative

#cv2_imshow(img_neg[2000])

#voxel form

#gaussian blur (sigma = 1)
gaus_blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_neg,(0,0), 1, 1)
```

Most of the solutions online mention that the images are not read correctly from the folder, but that's not the case, I tried to plot some and the dataset is exactly that one. Do you have any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: Which line of code gives you that error? Please show the full traceback, not just the error.

Comment: @AKX I edited it. The error is given by cv2.GaussianBlur itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the lack of context in your question still doesn't quite make it clear, it seems you're attempting to blur the *array* of images, not one 2D image

Blur each image on its own:

```
# could be some other structure than dicts, but it's not clear from the question
img = {}  
gaus_blur = {}

for k in range(7165):
    image = cv2.imread("/content/FIGURE/figure" + str(k) + ".png", 1)
    img[k] = image  # store original image
    gaus_blur[k] = cv2.GaussianBlur(255 - image, (0, 0), 1, 1)  # store inverse blurred image
```

Comment: That worked. `img` and `gaus_blur` were defined as `np.empty` vectors. Blurring them singularly was the way. Thank you!